# Nested optimization should never be triggered. This is probably due to autolayout work happening inside an NSISVariable delegate callback

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crash, autolayout

App crashed and log gave me this message:

"Nested optimization should never be triggered.  This is probably due to autolayout work happening inside an NSISVariable delegate callback, which is not allowed."

How to fix this?

Comment: Aslo i get this message in log: "This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.". Looks related.

Comment: Is this still an issue? If so, please provide the code generating the error message

Comment: I no longer get the same message. Think I was simply calling UI in a background thread, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yup. Glad you worked it out!

Comment: You can answer your own question and help others out who do something similar.

Comment: Where's the answer plz?

Answer (score 1):

Think I was updating UI in a background thread. Try putting: 
`if ([NSThread isMainThread]) { NSLog(@"isMainThread"); } else { NSLog(@"isNotMainThread"); }` next to UI updating lines, in order to find UI updates in background thread.

Example:

```
if ([NSThread isMainThread]) { NSLog(@"isMainThread"); } else { NSLog(@"isNotMainThread"); }
_MyLbl.text=@"some text";
```

if isNotMainThread is shown in log, replace the two lines with:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   _MyLbl.text=@"some text";
});
```

Not really an answer, more of a tip. But better than nothing I guess.